# Semi-circle layout

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm writing a playing-cards application, and I need to do the semi-circle (arc, half-round) layout. Search results gave me nothing. It needs to look something like this. but to allow more cards:

[image: Card hand]

Help would be appreciated!)

Comment: do a search for projecting a point along an angle.

Comment: or another hint: drawing objects around a center point

Comment: There are 180 degrees (π radians) in a half circle. Divide that by the number of objects, and that tells you the correct angle between the objects, for even spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a project, so anyone who'll need it feel free to use - https://github.com/Drabuna/semicircleas3
Example - http://drabuna.com/semi_circle/